# Comparar datos iguales seguidos de una tabla sql y php

Tags: php, sql

Hola estoy aprendiendo sql y php y me han puesto un ejercicio que os comento:

Mostrar un listado en el que aparezcan: todos los usuarios, resaltando visualmente (mediante color de letra o icono) aquellos registros donde su código postal se repita con su predecesor en el orden del listado.

Mi problema es que no se como hacer para comparar el código postal con el anterior dentro del array y que pasaría si es el primer registro ya que no hay uno anterior para compararlo. Me imagino que se hará con un if - else pero no se como compararlos. La tabla solo tiene el nombre, DNI y código postal.

Lo de cambiar el color de la letra me imagino que se hace en el echo al mostrar los datos eso no creo tener ningún problema en sacarlo solo es la comparación de los códigos postales con su anterior. Gracias.

Añado estoy probando y he añadido un if else dentro del while pero me sale error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="width:20%">
        <caption style="caption-side:top">Total Facturas usuarios ordenado por nombre:</caption>
        <thead style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Codigo Postal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <?php
        require ("Datos_conexion.php");
        $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la BBDD");
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

        $consulta="SELECT usuario.nombre, usuario.DNI, usuario.CP FROM usuario ORDER BY usuario.nombre";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        while($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            if ($dato["CP"]==$Primero) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $dato["nombre"] . "</td><td>" . $dato["DNI"] . "</td><td class='right rojo'>" . $dato["CP"] . "</td></tr><br>";
                $Primero=$dato["CP"];
            }
            else{
                echo "<tr><td>" . $dato["nombre"] . "</td><td>" . $dato["DNI"] . "</td><td class='right'>" . $dato["CP"] . "</td></tr><br>";
                $Primero=$dato["CP"];
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Usa un [`foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) y piensa que "lo de hoy, mañana será pasado".

Answer (score 0):

Vale me respondo ya que vi lo que me faltaba y era añadir $primero = 0;
quedaria así:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table" style="width:20%">
        <caption style="caption-side:top">Total Facturas usuarios ordenado por nombre:</caption>
        <thead style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Codigo Postal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <?php
        require ("Datos_conexion.php");
        $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la BBDD");
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");

        $consulta = "SELECT usuario.nombre, usuario.DNI, usuario.CP FROM usuario ORDER BY usuario.nombre";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        $primero = 0;
        while($dato = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            if ($dato["CP"]==$primero) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $dato["nombre"] . "</td><td>" . $dato["DNI"] . "</td><td class='right rojo'>" . $dato["CP"] . "</td></tr><br>";
                $primero=$dato["CP"];
            }
            else{
                echo "<tr><td>" . $dato["nombre"] . "</td><td>" . $dato["DNI"] . "</td><td class='right'>" . $dato["CP"] . "</td></tr><br>";
                $primero=$dato["CP"];
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```